# Preservation Under Unions

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I have a question about a certain covering property and why it is preserved under unions in a specific case.

**Terminology and Notation**:

- $X$ is an infinite topological space
- Letting $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ each be a collection of covers of $X$, we say $X$ satisfies S$_1(\mathscr{A}, \mathscr{B}$) if for each sequence $\{\mathcal{U}_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of members of $\mathscr{A}$, there exist members $U_n \in \mathcal{U}_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\{U_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \in \mathscr{B}$
- An open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ is an $\omega$-cover if for each finite $F \subseteq X$, there is a $U \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $F \subseteq U$.
- An open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ is a $\gamma$-cover if for each $x \in X$, $x$ is a member of all but finitely many members of $\mathcal{U}$.
- $\mathcal{\Omega}$ and $\mathcal{\Gamma}$ denote the collections of all $\omega$-covers and $\gamma$-covers of $X$, respectively.

While reading more about covering properties, I came across the following remark on section 9, page 98 in Open Problems in Topology II:

> It is easy to see that if $X$ satisfies $\mbox{S}_1 (\Omega, \Gamma)$ and $D$ is countable, then $X \cup D$ satisfies $\mbox{S}_1 (\Omega, \Gamma)$.

I'm trying to prove why this is true, but I'm not seeing why adding a countable set to a set satisfying $\mbox{S}_1 (\Omega, \Gamma)$ still preserves $\mbox{S}_1 (\Omega, \Gamma)$. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\langle\mathscr{U}_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence of $\omega$-covers of $X\cup D$. Enumerate $D=\{y_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $F_n=\{y_k\in D:k\le n\}$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\mathscr{V}_n=\{U\in\mathscr{U}_n:F_n\subseteq U\}$; it’s not hard to check that $\mathscr{V}_n$ is still an $\omega$-cover of $X\cup D$. $\langle\mathscr{V}_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is certainly a sequence of $\omega$-covers of $X$, so we can find a $\gamma$-cover $\{V_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of $X$ such that $V_n\in\mathscr{V}_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $y\in\Bbb N$; then $y_n\in F_k\subseteq V_k$ for each $k\ge n$, so $y_n$ is in all but finitely many of the sets $V_k$. Thus, $\{V_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is actually a $\gamma$-cover of $X\cup D$, and $V_n\in\mathscr{U}_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $X\cup D$ satisfies $S_1(\Omega,\Gamma)$.